# How to perform a loop to search strings contained in several files in awk and print new files?

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

I have this code to obtain several sequences for a list of entries. This matches each list (like OMA999.fas) in a big file with the sequences (sequences.fa)

```
awk 'NR==1{printf $0"\t";next}{printf /^>/ ? "\n"$0"\t" : $0}' sequences.fa | awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN{while((getline k <"OMA999.fas")>0)i[k]=1}{gsub("^>","",$0); if(i[$1]){print ">"$1"\n"$2}}'
```

This code worked fine. Now I would need a loop and I tried the following code but it seems it is not matching any string. I do not know if the structure of the for loop is wrong, but I think the part where it calls *`getline k < "$file"`* is working.

```
for file in *.fas; do awk 'NR==1{printf $0"\t";next}{printf /^>/ ? "\n"$0"\t" : $0}' sequences.fa | awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN{while((getline k < "$file")>0)i[k]=1}{gsub("^>","",$0); if(i[$1]){print ">"$1"\n"$2}}' > $(basename $file).nuc; done
```

I must add that the first code left a file renamed OMA999.fas.nuc with as many sequences as lines in the OMA file. Now I would want a list of .nuc files after the loop.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you want. Is it that you have a file with a bunch of patterns and you want to read those patterns from that file and then use the patterns to match lines in another file or series of files?

Comment: I did that with the first script. Now I want a loop for searching in a series of files containing different patterns, and return  files with the output of each search,  it would be a loop inside another loop let's say.

Comment: your existing first script looks highly redundant, please post a sample input/output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your awk script is contained in single quotes `' ... '`. This means that bash will not perform variable expansion and `$file` will be just treated as a string $-f-i-l-e, not the variable from the for loop. Changing that to double quotes *might* work, or it might just cause you a world of pain as the shell tries to expand awk variables too. Here is some documentation on how to probably best do it. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Shell-Variables.html

Other notes:

- I don't know enough `awk` to comment on your awk script, and I'm not entirely sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I have this hunch that your awk script is overly complicated.
- The strings that you are searching for are not changing so you do not need to re-read them every loop iteration. If you're not doing much work it doesn't hurt, but if you are, then this should be optimized.

Comment: "The strings that you are searching for are not changing so you do not need to re-read them every loop iteration."


I do not understand this. The strings are different in each file, each group formed is different since it groups sequences from different sets.
I could run this script over a few files containing lists, the problem is I have 87000 files with patterns to search.

Comment: OK, yes, that's where I am finding the strings and the entire record. I am using this solution since I need to recover the line plus the sequence below like

`>string matched
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`

Comment: _If I have answered your question, please accept the answer. Thanks._

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to explain further I was not dissenting, your answer was really helpful.

Comment: No no, I understand. And I'm happy to give more information. But if I have answered the question, click on the checkmark. It gives me points. ;-)